# CSS TABLE table row HEIGHT ISSUE

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I am facing an issue for the last hours and I cannot figure it out. I have defined a html table within my php script as follows:

```css
/* 
 Generic Styling, for Desktops/Laptops 
 */

#table_products {
  display: block;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  max-height: 300px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  overflow: auto;
  font-size: 11px;
}

table thead tr {
  height: 35px;
  max-height: 35px;
}


/* Zebra striping */

tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background: #eee;
}

th {
  background: #333;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}

td,
th {
  padding: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: -moz-pre-wrap !important;
  /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
  white-space: -pre-wrap;
  /* Opera 4-6 */
  white-space: -o-pre-wrap;
  /* Opera 7 */
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  /* css-3 */
  word-wrap: break-word;
  /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
  white-space: -webkit-pre-wrap;
  /* Newer versions of Chrome/Safari*/
  word-break: break-all;
  white-space: normal;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 760px),
(min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
  /* Force table to not be like tables anymore */
  table,
  thead,
  tbody,
  th,
  td,
  tr {
    display: block;
  }
  th {
    font-weight: bold;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  /* Hide table headers (but not display: none;, for accessibility) */
  thead tr {
    position: absolute;
    top: -9999px;
    left: -9999px;
  }
  tr {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
  }
  td {
    /* Behave  like a "row" */
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 50%;
  }
  td:before {
    /* Now like a table header */
    position: absolute;
    /* Top/left values mimic padding */
    top: 6px;
    left: 6px;
    width: 45%;
    padding-right: 10px;
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap !important;
    /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
    white-space: -pre-wrap;
    /* Opera 4-6 */
    white-space: -o-pre-wrap;
    /* Opera 7 */
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    /* css-3 */
    word-wrap: break-word;
    /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
    white-space: -webkit-pre-wrap;
    /* Newer versions of Chrome/Safari*/
    word-break: break-all;
    white-space: normal;
  }
  /*
  Label the data
  */
  td:nth-of-type(1):before {
    content: "X";
  }
  td:nth-of-type(2):before {
    content: "Προιόν";
  }
  td:nth-of-type(3):before {
    content: "#";
  }
  td:nth-of-type(4):before {
    content: "Τιμή+";
  }
}


/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px) {
  body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 320px;
  }
}


/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
  body {
    width: 495px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="table_products">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th style="width:7%">X</th>
        <th style="width:58%">Προιόν</th>
        <th style="width:15%">#</th>
        <th style="width:20%">Τιμή+</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>Salata </td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>22.5679</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>

  </table>
</div>
```

However I can not get the height of each row correctly. Both rows which I have in my table have height 50% and fill up the whole of 300px table height. I want the height of each row to be just 25px and to disregard the height of the table.

Any advice is appreciated

Comment: next time please provide a pen with the code so it is easily reviewed...
https://jsfiddle.net/k1a17vun/

Comment: Your semantics and styling really don't make any sense to me. Why not have just 4 rows with two cells each and use `display` properties instead of using positioning to 'hack' the layout of the table?